# Apollo Client query schema is not instance of GraphQLSchema

Tags: graphql, babeljs, apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to follow the [apollo client installation instructions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html).

I'm copying exactly what they are doing into my project, but whenever I call client.query, I get a 400 status code with the following error:

`Error: Schema must be an instance of GraphQLSchema. Also ensure that there are not multiple versions of GraphQL installed in your node_modules directory.`

This is all the code in my project's index.js:

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({ uri: 'https://q80vw8qjp.lp.gql.zone/graphql' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

client.query({ query: gql`{ hello }` }).then(console.log);
```

I've configured my babelrc file with the following option per the instructions in apollo's documentation:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "graphql-tag"
  ]
}
```

My project is just a basic webpack configuration with react. I've tried de-duping my npm packages, and checked if there are conflicting versions of graphql in my project but had no success. My best guess is that graphql-tag isn't working correctly and my query isn't being translated into the appropriate syntax for the request. It feels like I am missing something very basic. I would greatly appreciate any clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Weird...because [the default template](https://launchpad.graphql.com/new) works just fine and yours is identical...

Comment: I wonder if there's something else in my project but my config is super vanilla....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like an issue with your client config so much as a bug with Launchpad. If you access the GraphiQL interface for that endpoint and attempt to run a query, it'll throw the same error.

If you log into Launchpad with your Github account, you can start a new pad (which will be identical to that one), save it and then use that url in your project instead.

Comment: You rock. This perfectly fixed the issue. I had been pulling my hair out for a few hours!!!